# How to redirect a path without changing the URL while passing a GET parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Website: **example.com**
Link with GET parameter is sent to user through email: **example.com/click?var=1a2b3c** (<= random hash)

When the user clicks the link **"example.com/click?var=1a2b3c"**, he should be redirected to **"example.com/admin/click.php?var=1a2b3c"** where a function processes the GET parameter. The redirected URL should not be displayed and stay **"example.com/click?var=1a2b3c"**.

Who can help me out with the code for the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like you do not want a redirection at all, but an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=[a-z0-9_]+$
RewriteRule ^/?click$ /admin/click.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported [END] flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older [L] flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! I added the code inside my .htaccess but nothing really happend. When I go to "example.com/click?var=12345" I just get a HTTP Status 404. I also tried it with [L] instead of [END]. The result is the same. Maybe I should have said that the query string also contains random lowercase letters - so I replaced "\d+" with "\d+\w+". But still 404. Then I changed "^/?click$" to "^/click?$", because I thought you made a mistake. And now I get a 500.

Comment: I modified the pattern to accept lower case letters and digits.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you are not looking at a cached result from earlier attempts. So clear your browser cache or use an anonymous browser window for testing.

Comment: `^/click?$` does not make any sense, nor does `\d+\w+`. Try again with the pattern I suggested in an anonymous browser window.

Comment: Alright. I will try this out as soon as possible today. Is it important to add the line "Options +FollowSymLinks"?

Comment: Can't tell you. Do you have symbolic links in your server side file system that you want your http server to follow?

Comment: I have no idea, honestly. I still get the 404.

Comment: Please tripple check if you are really using the code shown in the answer, since you played around with it. Next is to make sure that the file get's executed at all and receives the request: place some definite syntax error in the file, make another request. What happens?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I am using WordPress and WordPress has a .htaccess file in its root folder. The .htaccess contains this code https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp and I think that this causes the 404. What do you think?

Comment: Mighty be, that depends in the folder structure and the final URL the WP installation is operated under. One of the many issues that arise from those dynamic configuration files (".htaccess").